# Propagate Type Parameters in Methods for Julia

Tags: types, julia

Julia (`v1.0`) is not propagating the free type parameters outside a method definition when using a type alias:

```
const RT{R<:Real} = Type{R}

rt(::RT{R}) where R = R
rt2(::Type{R}) where {R<:Real} = R
# there's more logic here for other subtypes
```

This works fine for `R<:Real`:

```
julia> rt(Int), rt2(Int) # works for both
(Int64, Int64)
```

But `rt()` freely accepts non-`<:Real` inputs

```
julia> rt(Char)
Char

julia> rt2(Char)    
MethodError: no method matching rt2(::Type{Char})
```

It seems that `rt2` keeps track of the `<:Real` upper bound, but `rt` does not:

```
julia> methods(rt)
# 1 method for generic function "rt":
[1] rt(::Type{R}) where R in Main at REPL[2]:1

julia> methods(rt2)
# 1 method for generic function "rt2":
[1] rt2(::Type{R}) where R<:Real in Main at REPL[3]:1
```

Is there anyway to automatically include the `R<:Real` constraint with a type-alias-like statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write (edited):

```
rt(r::RT) = r
```

and now

```
julia> methods(rt)
# 1 method for generic function "rt":
[1] rt(r::Type{R} where R<:Real) in Main at REPL[16]:1

julia> rt(Int)
Int64
```

and all works as expected. It looks like `where` clause in method definition, if present, overwrites the constraint in `const`. I am not sure if this is intended.

Comment: `rt(Int)` results in `ERROR: UndefVarError: R not defined`. Also, the method signature shows `rt(::Type{R} where R<:Real)` is different from `rt(::Type{R}) where R<:Real`, where in the second case `R` is defined outside of the parenthesis. It seems there is a scoping issue at play here.

Comment: Ah - right. I have fixed it. It was a scoping issue.