# Julia Type Parameters Nesting/Scope in Function Parameters

Tags: types, julia, type-variables

Following up from a [question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54655864/7288706), I am trying to understand the details of type parameter scope in function methods.
For example:

```
f(x::Vector{<:Number}) = sum(x)
g(x::Vector{T}) where T<:Number = sum(x)
```

The `<:Number` constraint covers only the argument list of `f`:

```
julia> methods(f)
f(x::Array{#s1,1} where #s1<:Number)
```

but it seems that `g` is parameterized by it:

```
julia> methods(g)
g(x::Array{T,1}) where T<:Number
```

Is there a reason why ["[y]ou generally want `T` to cover as little of the signature as possible"](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/20414#issuecomment-277110323) aside from [style](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/index.html#Don't-use-unnecessary-static-parameters-1) and limiting `T`'s scope?
Are there any implications performance, dispatch, or code-generation wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed `f` and `g` above are equivalent as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2540037/michael-k-borregaard) noted. You can dynamically check it by writing:

```
julia> f(x::Vector{<:Number}) = sum(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x::Vector{T}) where T<:Number = sum(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(f)
# 1 method for generic function "f":
[1] f(x::Array{T,1}) where T<:Number in Main at REPL[2]:1
```

And Julia tells you that the method definition was overwritten (so that it was deemed to be equivalent).

However, in general scoping does matter. See this example:

```
julia> f(::Vector{Vector{<:Real}}) = "inner"
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(::Vector{Vector{T}}) where {T<:Real}= "outer"
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f(::Any) = "all else"
f (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> methods(f)
# 3 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(::Array{Array{#s1,1} where #s1<:Real,1}) in Main at REPL[1]:1
[2] f(::Array{Array{T,1},1}) where T<:Real in Main at REPL[2]:1
[3] f(::Any) in Main at REPL[3]:1

julia> f([[1]])
"outer"

julia> f(Vector{<:Real}[[1]])
"inner"

julia> f([Any[1]])
"all else"
```

With regards to the performance in normal (i.e. type stable) code Julia performs static method dispatch so this should not matter. Probably you could design a contrived example requiring a complex dynamic method dispatch or dynamic code generation where this might matter (but for practical reasons this should not be relevant - just use the specification that represents your needs).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to spell it out :-)

Comment: I just thought that the question is general and not specific to these two functions given as an example.

Comment: Just a comment, maybe that is implicit, that `f(::Vector{Vector{<:Real}}) ` is equivalent to `f(::Vector{Vector{T} where {T <: Real}}) `

Comment: I agree I guess I just didn't understand what the general question was about - not sure I do still

Comment: Could you point me to a reference (Julia docs?) where the difference between the `"inner"` and `"outer"` case is explained? As a Julia neophyte I thought that `"inner"` is a shorthand for `"outer"`. Now I am confused ... Is that because the where clause is outside the parameter tuple?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#UnionAll-Types-1, the example with `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: Uuh, that's subtle. Thanks a lot for the link!

Answer (score 1):

The `f` and `g` syntaxes are identical, so no difference.